# enviroment variable %PROGRAMFILES% with 2 executions

Tags: batch, environment-variables

I want to install a program with a batch-file to the *Program Files* folder. Afterwards I want to copy a folder to the same folder. Here is an example:

```
SET SCRIPT_LOCATION=%~dp0
SET INSTALLATION_PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\example program

"%SCRIPT_LOCATION%\example program\setup.exe"
```

Now additional files should be copied to the program folder:

```
xcopy "%SCRIPT_LOCATION%\additional_files" "%INSTALLATION_PATH%example program\additional_files" /E
```

The problem is, that the program supports only 32bit. That means the program will be installed under *"C:\Program Files (x86)\example program"* on a 64bit machine.

But when the copy is executed, the files will be installed under *"C:\Program Files\example program\additional files"*. But the additional files should be installed to the same path as the program.

I know that the operating systems decides which path should be used when *%PROGRAMFILES%* is used. The OS checks if the program supports 64bit maschines or not.

I think a possible solution would be to ask for the machine type (32/64bit) and decide whether  *%PROGRAMFILES%* or *%PROGRAMFILES (x86)%* should be used with an if-clause. Or is there a way to parse the path from the installation to a variable and use it later for the copy?

Are there any other nice ways to include environment variables for my problem?

Comment: Try `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`

Comment: Which operating systems are you targeting?

Comment: The best would be xp up to win8 and 32bit/64bit machines. I want the highest compatibility.